# Moving an application between discs (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, dll

I recall an Application from my Vista days data provided from moving an application (its executable, all affiliated DLLs and all the dependencies thereof) I have basically filled up my C: drive and have a lot of room on my D: drive. So I wish to move applications from C: to D:

Any ideas?

Comment: In Super User, and all the StackExchange sites, shopping or product recommendations are considered off topic and open ended, and sometimes even too localized. Try to reword your question in a way that you are not asking for products, but more of processes; this will help keep it on topic

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I mklink junction + move content from C:\Program Files to D:\Program Files?](http://superuser.com/questions/390636/how-do-i-mklink-junction-move-content-from-c-program-files-to-d-program-file)

Answer (score 1):

Move the contents of the application folder to a new folder on your D: drive, then delete the old folder and replace it with
a symbolic link that has the same name as the old folder, pointing to the new folder. You use the mklnk command in a command prompt window to do this.

Comment: I was able to copy C:/Program Files over to D: without any problem. Looking at C:\Program Files and its properties I was unable to see the location tab to do a move. Using the administrator command prompt what is the exact syntax I should be using? I'd rather have the operating system files move the files then to magically link to files I copied in an unrelated operation.